# Correct use of new & delete on Structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I'm a beginner in C++. I have an exercise in which I have to add, delete an modify data on a struct. So if I define the struct:

```
struct Student {
        string name;
        int ID;
        double grade;
    };
```

Will it be correct to use: `new Student student` each time I want to add a new student? And for each time I want to delete a student, can I do it this way?

```
delete student;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new Student` will allocate a new instance of the `Student` class. You have not provided sufficient information to determine whether this will be sufficient to "add a new student". Ditto for deleting a student. Generally, in modern C++, `new`/`delete` is rarely needed, as C++ containers will generally be sufficient for the purpose of maintaining dynamic collections of objects.

Comment: I am thinking: how will you use the struct? I am worrying that you may be having a (wrong) impression that you have to write `new` whenever you want to use a struct.

Comment: I need to store X number of students with those properties in my program. So I decided to use structs but I'm probably just making it more complicated. Can you suggest a better (and easier) way of doing this?

Comment: An array of structs, or the answer below with vector.

Comment: @DanielHerrera - `std::vector<Student> StudentArray(X);`  -- That is all you need to do to have X number of students.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use of new and delete, you can try :

```
Student* student = new Student;
delete student;
```

Besides, there is a better way. You can use C++ containers such as vector:

```
vector<Student> student;//You should add "#include <vector>"

//When you want to add a new student
Student temp;
getline(cin,temp.name);
cin>>temp.ID;
cin>>temp.grade;
student.push_back(temp);

//And When delete a student
student.pop_back();
```

Answer (score -3):

To be able for you to add Student, delete Student, or modify Student, without using standard library, you need to define additional struct to manage students. You will also need to add id as additional field for student.

```
struct StudentList {    // Declaration: StudentList sl = new StudenList;
    Student *list;      // linkedlist used to store any number of students
    Student *next;      // pointer used to traverse to the next node of list
    add(Student s)      // Usage: Student s = new Student("Anne",15,3); sl.add(s);
    delete(int id);     // Usage: std::cin >> id; ls.delete(id);
                        // Deletes student record with id matching the parameter.
    modify(int id);     // Usage: std::cin >> id; ls.modify(id);
                        // Modifies student record with id matching the parameter.
}
```

of course the in the implementation of this functions, you will need to check the number of students in the list and make sure it doesn't go beyond its range (0 - max).  Since linked list is used in this method, you need to implement the code to create node, delete node, and traversing from head node to tail.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are trying to learn C/C++ that's why i presented creating your own linked list instead of using stl libraries such as std::list or vector. Learning by reinventing the wheel will give you a solid foundation of how the internal process works. Soon you can start using the ready made libraries or even extend it for custom needs of your project.

Comment: *Learning by reinventing the wheel will give you a solid foundation of how the internal process works* -- All it will do is turn off the learner to C++ and have him/her go to Java.

Comment: As long as you are aware of your intentions that your doing that for the sake of learning, it's going to be a productive path. Instead of using the libraries without understanding what's happening behind it. When a feature is not supported by a library and you need a custom one, you will always end up asking other people who've done it here instead of solving the problem by your self.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have a different opinion. Wheel reinvention is not by itself a bad way to learn things. The true problems are: (1) It is not the good learning stage to do so; (2) The quality of the reference design of the wheel is not guaranteed; (3) It distracts from the actual learning objective of the exercise.